# Where Does /var/lib/nginx/proxy Come From?

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I have a server configured to proxy by setting:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=backcache:8m max_size=20g inactive=7d;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$is_args$args";
```

Despite this, when I start nginx, I end up with /var/lib/nginx/proxy as well.  BOTH started filling up and eventually the hard drive filled up.

If I try making my proxy_cache_path point to /var/lib/nginx/proxy instead, I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] the same path name "/var/lib/nginx/proxy" used in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:1 and in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Line 62 of nginx.conf is just the end of the http{} section, so I assume this is complaining about the "default" that I'm attempting to override.

I can't figure out how to disable this proxy config which appears to be duplicating the explicit config I've set up.  Is there a way to override/remove that default proxy configuration?

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the issue was that `/var/lib/nginx/proxy` is the `proxy_temp_path`. Normally nginx will download to this temp path and then *move* the files over to the **real** cache directory once they've finished downloading.

We must have had a lot of things that didn't finish downloading, or never made it over into the main cache, so the disk filled up.

The solution in this case was to just turn use of the temp_path off (with the `use_temp_path=off` parameter on the `proxy_cache_path` directive on nginx 1.7.10 or higher).

Comment: To add on, you have to manually delete those files/directories in `/var/lib/nginx/proxy` a well placed `rm -rf` should do it.